# Фильтр EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

В моём небольшом проекте есть 2 `EditText`, как сделать так, чтобы пользователь в первом `EditText` мог ввести данные только от 00 до 23, а во втором от 00 до 59?

Понимаю, что это надо делать при помощи `InputFilter`, но толковых гайдов не нашёл. Может кто разжевать?

Answer (score 3):

InputFilter срабатывает в момент замены какой-то подстроки какой-то [под]строкой. И задача поверить ввод, чтоб не давать вводить невалидные символы. Например, можно придумать регулярку (более краткий вариант), которая будет пропускать инкрементный ввод, т.е. давать вводить посимвольно. Или в случае простого ввода, как в вопросе, просто проверять соответствующие диапазоны...

С регулярками, например, так:

```
public class TimeFilter implements InputFilter {
    private final Pattern mPattern;

    public TimeFilter(Pattern pattern){
        this.mPattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        // Получаем результат ввода как замену вырезанного из dest на source
        // при обычном вводе dstart==dend - позиция в которой произошел ввод
        String result =
                dest.subSequence(0, dstart)
                        + source.toString()
                        + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(result);
        // Если результат не соответствует регулярке, возвращаем кусок,
        // который удалился бы, т.е. то, что заменили в dest.
        // При обычном вводе, возвращается пустая строка
        // Или оригинальное выделение, если что-то было выделено
        if (!matcher.matches()) return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
        // Ввод соответствует регулярке
        return null;
    }
}
```

Для часов фильтр такой (в регулярках не особо силен, но вроде должно работать):

```
new TimeFilter(Pattern.compile("^(([0-1]([0-9]){0,1})?|(2([0-3]){0,1})?)$"));
```

Для минут такой:

```
new TimeFilter(Pattern.compile("^([0-5]([0-9]){0,1})?$"));
```

Если просто проверка диапазонов, то

```
...
if(result.isEmpty()) return null;
try {
  int v = Integer.parseInt(result);
  if(v>23 || v<0) return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
}
...
```

С лидирующими нулями разберитесь самостоятельно.

Comment: Я сам новичок, а что значит "регулярка"?

Comment: @Ivan [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярное_выражение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярное_выражение)